# Integrating Prolog with C#

Tags: c#, prolog, integrate

Does anyone know of a nice (and preferably free) way to integrate Prolog and C#?

Im looking to create a Prolog dll or similar to call from my managed code, and retrieve an answer once all the processing has been complete. Im looking for it to be predominantly one sided (c# calls Prolog).

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130097/real-world-prolog-usage) which talks about Prologs real world usage but I was wondering if anyone had either any experience with c# & Prolog? or a nice tutorial/article?

Comment: Hey Greg,
I was curious what route you'd taken with this Prolog/C# integration and any luck you've had. In same boat here. Thx. -Al

Answer (score 8):

You can take a look at [Yield Prolog](http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/).

Yield Prolog uses `yield` keyword in C# (and Python, and JavaScript) and custom `Variable` class to simulate Prolog machine. This way, you get a Prolog API in your favourite language. You don't need to connect your main language with P# or similiar projects.

Answer (score 3):

It's not free, but [Sicstus Prolog](http://www.sics.se/isl/sicstuswww/site/highlights.html) allows connection to C# and Java

This is the Prolog implementation we use at our company, and it is very fast and useful.

Comment: I have used Sicstus in the past and found it to be a very good product. I wasn't aware that it can connect with c#, the only problem now it the rather large licence fee!

Answer (score 3):

C#Prolog, [available from SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-prolog/) (Prolog interpreter written in C#)

Comment: Here is the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-prolog/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [P#](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/jjc/psharp/psharp-1.1.3/dlpsharp.html) will be useful for you

Comment: This link is broken now, know anywhere else that has information on this?

Comment: [This](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/jjc/psharp/psharp-1.1.3/dlpsharp.html) is still working as of posting this comment.

Answer (score 2):

If your prolog is swi-prolog, you have two choices. 
The older, and essentially deprecated, version is http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.html

The newer, much better one is swicli.
http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/NetMono.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ECLiPSe Prolog.
i have integrated it with VC8. it would be better to use VC8 instead of C#.

Answer (score 0):

If deployment with a full prolog implementation is not a problem you can use SWI-Prolog and talk to it via XPCE and sockets.