# How can I connect C# and Sicstus prolog?

Tags: c#, prolog, sicstus-prolog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrating Prolog with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181855/integrating-prolog-with-c)

I am trying to connect prolog project with C#. How can i Do this?