# C# as user interface calling Prolog as reasoning module

Tags: c#, api, module, prolog, integrate

I need to write a program using C# as user interface and getting input. Then after that, use Prolog to calculate the answer, and give back to C# to display. A school project :D

Please advise on how to do this, any free API i can use ? I know C# but sucks at Prolog ( which is done by another member of the team ), so if there's any way I don't need to touch Prolog at all is prefered. Really thanks for your help

Comment: What version of Prolog are you using? There are several different commercial Prolog products available, and their ability to interop with .Net will vary.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181855/integrating-prolog-with-c-sharp

Comment: I'm using Amzi prolog, school version. I need free products.

Comment: I've looked at that question too, tried out a few of the suggestion but doesn't look like what I need... or maybe I didn't try the right one ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [link](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/ls/lsadotnet.htm) for you on the Amzi Prolog web site that describes the integration to .Net.

Comment: Hey looks like what I need. Checking it out. Thanks a bunch in advance