# Connect prolog code with C# program

Tags: prolog, ffi

I have a prolog code for searching a book. It is a simple game. I want to make interfaces with C#. But i don't know how to connect prolog into c#. Please help me. How to conncet prolog with C#.

Comment: you could start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181855/integrating-prolog-with-c-sharp

Comment: What Prolog interpreter are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the answers mentioned on the [comment link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181855/integrating-prolog-with-c-sharp) there is also a SWI Prolog has a C# Interface. You can see it [**here**.](http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.txt)

Here is an example provided by the aforementioned link:

```
PlQuery q = new PlQuery("member(A, [a,b,c])");
foreach (PlTermV s in q.Solutions)
    Console.WriteLine(s[0].ToString());
```

There is a [**full documentation**](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx).