# P# in C# - The type or namespace name 'Call_3' does not exist in the namespace 'JJC.Psharp.Predicates'

Tags: c#, prolog

I'm new to the p# and c# user, and i wish to connect C# program to the prolog and get the output from prolog, 
however, when i put the file generated by the p# console to the c# directory and try to run it, it give this error

**"Error    6   The type or namespace name 'Call_3' does not exist in the namespace 'JJC.Psharp.Predicates' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"**

What should I do to solve this question? Your help is highly appreciate.

Comment: `your_predicat.cs` is it created correctly inside PSharp-interpreter?

Comment: Yes, i compiled my .pl file using the  PSharp-interpreter.

Comment: However, besides the predicate I defined my self, I also used pre-defined function like max(x,y), exclude(X,Y,Z) and maplist(X,Y). And when I tried to run the program after put in all the .cs file generated, the error occur and namespace name 'exclude_3', 'maplist_3' doest not exist in the namespace. After that, I copy the prolog code for maplist exclude from the internet and compile it to .cs files again, and another error, predefined function 'call_3' pops out again.

Comment: FYI, it's not like that to integrate the missing `built-in` predicates such as `exclude` or `maplist`

Comment: Opps... If that case, what should I do to integrate these missing predicates ?

Comment: If you're in preliminary stages to learn prolog like me,
avoid to use the complex structure of implementation of the built-in predicates, and I advice you to use the recursive structure through simple examples .

Comment: I hope that this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/181855/5719394) will be help you

Comment: Thanks for your advice =)